# Вывести все значения explode

Tags: php

Нужно вывести все значения. Код ниже работает, но думаю что есть варианты получше.

```
$ex = '0|1|500|50';
$pref = explode('|', $ex);
while($row = each($pref)) {
echo $row[1].', ';
}
```

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводится к завершению задач за учащихся. Приведите пример вашей реализации и задайте вопрос с описанием конкретных проблем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты издеваешься что ли? Мана [тут](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).
Вот так:

```
$ex = '0|1|500|50';
$pref = explode('|', $ex);
print implode(', ', $pref);
```

**А лучше так:**

[Функции для работы с массивами.](https://php.net/manual/ru/ref.array.php)